# Microservices waiting on responses from other services

Tags: soa, restful-architecture, microservices

I recently encountered a question where a person asked me what would you do in the following scenario:

You have service A, service B, and service C interacting with one another. Service A can only perform its full functionality if it receives response from B and C. However, C has a lot of requests queued and will take a long time to respond. How would service A handle this scenario? Will service A wait and wait until C will respond even after getting the response from B? How will you make this architecture faster?

Comment: The answer heavily depends on requirement and context.

There are many questions to be asked here:
1. What is the rate at which A gets these requests.
2. How stale a data can be.
3. What should happen in case of failure.
4. What resources do I have. (eg can I spun a new service , add a cashing layer , modify A/B/C etc).

Answer (score 1):

I see a fundamental issue with this statement:

> Service A can only perform its full functionality if it receives response from B and C

If your components (services) are not autonomous you have a serious flaw in the initial design. When decomposing a system you want to end up with a logical boundary that allows each "Service"/"Component" autonomous and explicitly a technical authority of the part of the system it owns.

So `Service A` will do it's job and publish an event that `Service B` subscribes to and will do it's bit and then `B` will publish an event that `C` will subscribe to an ddo it's portion of the business process.

If they can do the work in parallel then the creator (the client who send the initial commands with the data) can send the command directly to each component and you might have a component tracking the business process state by subscribing to events the component would publish when they complete their units of work.

The actual design is very context dependent so it would be hard to decompose the domain without the specific details.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your C service is a bottleneck of your system. Solutions are:

1. Scale C service. You should have a load balancer and more C service nodes.
2. Use cache for C service results.
3. Change your architecture with splitting C logic into 2 microservices.